# Many strange file with random 6 characters name are created in the root folder in a short time

Tags: debian

We found many strange files with random 6 characters name are created in the root folder in a short time at our linux server (Debian wheezy hosting in Google compute engine).

All the files are with root/root and 0600 permission.

```
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:29 0QOenG
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:33 1z5U2y
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:43 1zTOzN
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:34 23XZoM
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:32 27zsbT
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:27 2Wm0aJ
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:41 398ekH
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:38 3dI8Es
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:33 3kskdR
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:37 3lWyRD
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:33 3PX7Fx
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:32 3RDbjb
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:33 43yJsH
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:27 4_Efvb
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:30 4hAx0N
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:43 4Oljiz
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:33 4OR5Pi
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:42 4TmJLl
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:29 4YFfes
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:31 5451XV
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:30 569_O4
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:37 57kOaP
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:39 5Alljw
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:42 5_ucGQ
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:27 5x4ctz
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:35 60nv0J
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:32 68ir6n
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:37 6BnyKZ
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:41 6JOkrT
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:38 6wFyZl
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:41 6WW7nj
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:33 6YYyta
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:35 7N9JJU
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:42 7uVRTI
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:29 8r071y
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:34 8yT2UG
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:40 9e30rd
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:35 9JvGnk
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:32 9sJWOd
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:30 9ud9NZ
    -rw------- 1 root root 0 Sep 20 06:30 9yslgU
```

BTW, the boot disk was almost full due to a large log file around the time that the files created. And after the large log file is deleted, the strange files are not created anymore.

PS. The following services runs at the server:

mongodb, postgresql, redis, activemq, fluentd

Can someone explain who created these files?

Comment: Can't say for certain given the limited information. Best I can say is they were likely generated with something akin to `tempfile`.

Comment: Are the files still being created, or was this a one-time occurrence? If it may happen again, it may be possible to watch the directory for changes and catch the process that creates them.

Comment: @Alexander It's a one-time occurrence. But thank you for the suggestion. it's a very good way to investigate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file name pattern is standard for the [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktemp) (or [`mkstemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp)) function, when passed the simplest possible template (`"XXXXXX"` while running in the root directory). So this could be pretty much any program.

If the program has stopped doing this, it's impossible to find out with complete certainty what program is the culprit after the fact. However, there's a good chance that the program is still doing it, and if it is you can catch it in the act.

This program is evidently buggy since it shouldn't be creating a lot of temporary files. If the files appeared while the disk was full, there's a good chance that the program in fact frequently creates such temporary files; but under normal operation, it fills them with content, processes them and finally deletes them. When the disk is full, the filling step fails but the file is not removed because the program doesn't recover from the error correctly.

You can use [Linux's audit facility](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/simple-example-auditd-configuration) to watch activity in a directory. Make sure that `auditd` is installed and set up a watch [on the root directory itself](https://superuser.com/questions/650714/auditd-auditctl-rule-to-monitor-dir-only-not-all-sub-dir-and-files-etc) (not a recursive watch!):

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F path=/
```

You'll get log messages in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` when a process writes to the root directory. This should pretty much never happen under normal operation, so the problematic process will stand out.

Comment: Get a "auditdError sending add rule data request (Invalid argument)" when try to use `auditctl -a exit,always -F path=/` . We can't watch the `/` folder?

Comment: @hoozecn Oh, damn, you can't set a watch on `/`, it's a special protection. It makes sense to forbid a *recursive* watch on `/`, I wonder why a non-recursive watch is a problem. I need to think about this. You can watch when those file creations occur with `inotifywatch /`, inotify watches do work on `/`, but they only report the file operation, they don't report what process caused it. You can try `inotify /` and to immediately run `lsof` on the new file, but due to timing it may not catch the process in time, if the temporary file is very short-lived.